# How to capture intermediate values with Mockito?

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

The problem is simple...

```
// Class Under Test
list.add(1);
dependency.handleList(list);
list.clear();
list.add(2);
dependency.handleList(list);

//Test Code
verify(mockDepenency, times(2)).handleList(argumentCaptor.capture());
List<Collection<Integer>> list = argumentCaptor.getAllValues();
assertEquals(1, list.get(0).get(0)); // fails value is 2
```

The reason seems to be related to the way Mockito captures arguments. That is, it captures all arguments by reference. This seems to be related to [this issue](https://code.google.com/p/mockito/issues/detail?id=126).

Ideally I would like to be able to specify a copy/clone on capture but I don't see a way to do that. Are there alternatives that I am missing?

Comment: I think that issue you linked to is a little easier to understand than your example (no offense).  For your example, can't you just verify between `dependency.handList` calls?

Comment: @tieTYT: no because handleList is called in the class that I am testing (thus the Class User Test comment) so there will be no mockito or juint calls in the class I am actually trying to test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are supplying `list` to the class under test, you could perhaps mock that also and perform verification on it, for example:

```
final List<Integer> list = spy(List.class);

... act...

final InOrder inOrder = inOrder(list, mockDependency);

inOrder.verify(list).add(1);
inOrder.verify(mockDependency).handleList(list);
inOrder.verify(list).clear();
inOrder.verify(mockDependency).handleList(list);
inOrder.verify(list).add(2);
```

However, I'm not sure how this approach would hold up for your actual test.

**EDIT:** Changed from `mock` to `spy` based on whaley's comment.

Comment: Personally, I would spy an actual List implementation here instead of a mock of List.class so that add/clear can be used as normal without writing when statements to stub those out.

Comment: @Jonathan: the list is actually built inside the method but power mockito can intercept the `new` call. +1 from me and I'll probably accept this but I'm leaving the question open for a bit longer to see if anyone else bites.